# How to transpose 4 rows in a data frame including two columns and show them as column using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

```
date    time    value
0   01-01-2000  00:00   1
1   01-01-2000  00:00   2
2   01-01-2000  00:00   3
3   01-01-2000  00:00   4
4   01-01-2000  01:00   5
5   01-01-2000  01:00   6
6   01-01-2000  01:00   7
7   01-01-2000  01:00   8
```

i have above dataframe i wants to result out to below format

```
date    time    value   col1  col2  col3  col4
0   01-01-2000  00:00   1      2     3     4
1   01-01-2000  01:00   5      6     7     8
```

data list

```
date = ['01-01-2000','01-01-2000','01-01-2000','01-01-2000','01-01-2000','01-01-2000','01-01-2000','01-01-2000']
time = ['00:00','00:00','00:00','00:00','01:00','01:00','01:00','01:00']
value = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df['g'] = df.groupby(['time','time']).cumcount() 

f = lambda x: f'col{x + 1}'
df = df.pivot(['date','time'], 'g', 'value').rename(columns=f).reset_index()
print (df)
g        date   time  col1  col2  col3  col4
0  01-01-2000  00:00     1     2     3     4
1  01-01-2000  01:00     5     6     7     8
```

Alternative is aggregate `list`s and then create `DataFrame` by costructor:

```
s = df.groupby(['date','time'])['value'].agg(list)

f = lambda x: f'col{x + 1}'
df = pd.DataFrame(s.tolist(), index=s.index).rename(columns=f).reset_index()

print (df)
         date   time  col1  col2  col3  col4
0  01-01-2000  00:00     1     2     3     4
1  01-01-2000  01:00     5     6     7     8
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer, i have data with 700000+ rows entry,when i tried above code its showing error,'IndexError: index 1873575780 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1873569152'

Comment: @GaneshM - Can you check alternative?